# where is Bios setting of VMware machine?

Tags: windows

this problem is rise during am trying to install server using ISO file(with out C).This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems. However, 64-bit operation is not possible.

This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.

Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.

(1) Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution.'

(2) Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.

(3) Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing machine Workstation.

(4) Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.

Then I filled Hyper-V box in the " Turn on/off Windows feature " but I faced this error again , so I decided to change BIOS/firmware setting but I could not find it ( even I set the Hyper-V box to the first situation ) . What should I do ?

Comment: *I decided to change BIOS/firmware setting but I could not find it* are you saying you couldn't find it in the BIOS of your physical machine? It's usually located under the `Security` tab in the BIOS.

Comment: HI. i don't know where is bios setting is in virtual machine

Comment: It's not a setting that is edited on the virtual machine. Enabling Intel VT-x is changed on your physical machine that is hosting the VM. So you'll need to power down your physical PC and enter the BIOS.